# Сортировка ассоциативного массива по ключю

Tags: база-данных, php

Доброго времени суток. Необходимо отсортировать ассоциативный массив по ключу. В частности, у меня в магазине формируется массив с необходимыми данными. Необходимо по категориям товаров отсортировать их, чтобы одинаковые категории шли рядом и при добавлении, после такой же категории, они вставали рядом. Надеюсь понятно написал ). Пока не получается самому отсортировать, читаю документацию. Кто знает, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Сортировка товаров с одинаковой категорией. В тот массив, в который записываются все данные по товару, скорее всего, его бесполезно сортировать. Я пока не придумал как правильно оформить условие. Уже, когда товары выводятся, если категория одна (поле будет равно с одинаковой категорией), их нужно выводить по порядку. Можно ли пройтись по всему массиву, прежде чем выводить его, или надо сформировать новый отсортированный массив. Пока непонятно как это будет работать после добавления товара нового в корзину.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[usort() — Sort an array by values using a user-defined comparison function](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

```
$array = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'category_name' => 'category_2'),
    array('id' => 2, 'category_name' => 'category_3'),
    array('id' => 3, 'category_name' => 'category_1')
);

usort($array, function($l, $r) { 
    return strcmp($l["category_name"], $r["category_name"]); 
});

var_dump($array);
```

Comment: я на обед пошел. ваш пример вставлял и на свой массив заменял, все равно ошибка Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in Z:\home\testpzbf\www\components\com_virtuemart\themes\default\templates\basket\basket_b2c.html.php on line 29 видимо функцию нужно раньше объявить и в usort ($array, "function_name") наверно так надо

Comment: function sort_cat($l, $r) {return strcmp($l["category_name"], $r["category_name"]);} usort($product_rows, "sort_cat");

вот что в итоге получилось

Answer (score 3):

[ksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) же!

**Добавлено**

```
$ar = array(
    'v' => 'aaa',
    'd' => 'bbb',
    'b' => 'vvv',
    'a' => 'ddd',
);
ksort($ar);
print_r($ar);
```

Так делаете?

Comment: Не сортирует так. Перепробовал все варианты в справочнике. Даже если указываю так `ksort($array, $element)`.

Comment: да. у меня в массив получаются данные из базы, затем он по ключам выводится в шаблоне. вот я и думаю как отсортировать его по определенному ключу.

это часть того что print_r выводит Array ( [0] => Array ( [row_color] => sectiontableentry1 [product_name] => Boom
[product_attributes] => [product_sku] => BM-SND-502 [product_thumb_image] => resized/Boom_4e4376dacd1a9_100x120.jpg [product_packaging] => 0 [category_name] => Записные книжки [product_price] => 45.41 .руб [subtotal] => 45.41 .руб [subtotal_with_tax] => 45.41 .руб

Comment: Нужно отсортировать по этому полю `[category_name] => Тетради общие 96 листов`

Comment: Тогда сделайте print_r массиву и посмотрите, те ли ключи сортируете.

Comment: то что print_r выводит написано выше и ключ как называется написан выше. пробовал ksort($product_rows, $category_name) - 0 результата. Нужно просто чтобы вывод продуктов шел по порядку их категорий. если они одинаковые. то просто по порядку их. Хотя может я и не правильно думаю про сортировку. может что то другое нужно сортировать, а не сам массив

Comment: Стоп. На кой вам ksort($product_rows, $category_name), если на входе функции должен быть один массив? Все, что идет после массива - дополнительные параметры. Если у вас массив товаров - $goods, то и пишите ksort($goods) .

Answer (score 0):

А "order by `category_name` asc" дописать в запросе к БД?

Comment: Об этом я тоже думал, но это VM и чтобы не копаться в куче файлов, сэкономить время). Потому, может и знает кто способ просто сортировки уже при выводе массива с данными. Там отдельно массив формируется с данными, и выборка из сортированной базы даст тот же результат. Мне так кажется.

Comment: administrator\components\com_virtuemart\classes\ps_product_category.php
function get_child_list($category_id)

$q .= "ORDER BY #__{vm}_category.list_order, #__{vm}_category.category_name ASC";

попробуй заменить на 

$q .= "ORDER BY #__{vm}_category.category_name ASC";

Это в случае если тебе нужно вывести подкатегории стандартным выводом

Comment: мне не подкатегории нужно) я добавил вообще вывод категории для каждого продукта. $product_rows[$i]['category_name'] = $ps_product_category->get_field($cart[$i]["category_id"], "category_name");
соответственно по каждому товару формируется свой массив. потом он в цикле прогоняется <?php foreach( $product_rows as $product ) {  ?>
дальше уже вывод данных для каждого товара из массива. сортировать не сам массив нужно, а уже вывод данных)